# Dependency Injection in .Net Web Api 2.2 endpoint not available

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have a console application which works quit like a web api.
At the Program.cs I register

```
var collection = new ServiceCollection();
collection.AddScoped<IInfoBusinessComponent, InfoBusinessComponent>();
```

The InfoBusinessComponent need also a dependency injection which I do before adding the InfoBusinessComponent. Also I register my ILogger.

At my InfoController I use the di like that:

```
public InfoController(IInfoBusinessComponent businessComponent, ILogger<InfoController> logger)
```

When I call now that endpoint, I get immediately a 500 response.
When I erase the arguments from the controller, than the process is going into the constructor and controller. But that's not what I want.

```
    public InfoController()
```

**Why is the constructor not getting the dependency injection or why is the constructor not called?**

```
public class Program
{
    #region fields and propetries
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }  
    //# if DEBUG
    //#endif
    public static IConnection Connection { get; set; }
    public static ITimeSeriesBusinessComponent TimeSeriesBusinessComponent { get; set; }
    public static IInfoBusinessComponent InfoBusinessComponent { get; set; }
    private static int counter;
    #endregion fields and propetries

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IConfiguration config = GetConfigurations();
        ILogger logger = GetLogger();
        ServiceProvider appServiceProvider = GetServiceProvider(config);

        Parallel.Invoke
        (
            () =>
            {
                BuildWebHost(args).Build().Run();
            }, 
            () =>
            {
                //...
            }
        );


    }

    private static IConfiguration GetConfigurations()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
            .Build();
        return config;
    }

    private static ILogger GetLogger()
    {
        ILogger logger = new LoggerFactory().AddNLog().CreateLogger<Program>();
        return logger;
    }

    private static ServiceProvider GetServiceProvider(IConfiguration config)
    {
        var collection = new ServiceCollection();
        collection.AddLogging(configuration => configuration.AddNLog());
        //...
        collection.AddScoped<IInfoRepository>(serviceProvider =>
        {
            return new InfoRepository(
                config["ConnectionStrings:MainConnection"], 
                config["ConnectionStrings:MetaDataConnection"],
                config["InfoFunctionName"],
                config["UserName"],
                config["Password"],
                config["VirtualHost"],
                config["ConnectionHostName"]);
        });
        collection.AddScoped<IInfoBusinessComponent, InfoBusinessComponent>();
        var appServiceProvider = collection.BuildServiceProvider();
        return appServiceProvider;
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5003")
            .UseNLog();
}
```

Here the Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Title = "My CLI"
            });
        });
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My CLI");
            c.DocExpansion(Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.DocExpansion.None);
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Comment: What your Startup class looks like? I don't see how appServiceProvider ever gets into the pipeline...

Comment: @felix-b I added the Startup.cs to my initial post. You say that you don't see how my appServiceProvider gets into the pipeline. I assume that the setting collection.AddScoped<IClass, Class>() is enough for the software to know and use the dependency injection objects.

Comment: I would manage all my services in the ConfigureServices method.... That is what that method is for in the first place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the endpoint you create with `BuildWebHost` uses its own instance of `ServiceProvider`. The instance of `ServiceProvider` that you create doesn't get into the pipeline.

**Why:** `ServiceCollection` doesn't use any kind of singleton registry, so it's not enough to register services through some instance of `ServiceCollection` and build some instance of `ServiceProvider`. You have to make the endpoint use your specific instance of `ServiceCollection`/`ServiceProvider`. Or you can copy your `ServiceCollection` into one that's used by the endpoint - that's how I'd solve it.

So, let's use a `ServiceCollection` to register your services (as it is now). Then, instead of doing `collection.BuildServiceProvider()`, let's use that `ServiceCollection` in the `Startup`, to copy all registrations into the service collection used by the pipeline.

First, let's expose your `ServiceCollection` to be accessible from `Startup`:

```cs
class Program
{
    public static ServiceCollection AppServices { get; set; }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // ...other stuff...

        AppServices = GetServiceCollection(config);

        // ...other stuff...
    }

    // renamed from GetServiceProvider
    private static ServiceCollection GetServiceCollection(IConfiguration config)
    {
        var collection = new ServiceCollection();

        // ... register services...

        return collection;
    }
}
```

Then in the `Startup` class, use `Program.AppServices` in `ConfigureServices()` as follows:

**EDIT**: pay attention to the `using`s in Startup.cs

```cs
// make sure these usings are present:
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;

....

public class Startup
{
    // ... other members ...

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ... the usual stuff like services.AddMvc()...

        // add this line:
        services.TryAdd(Program.AppServices);
    }

    // ... other members ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your article Felix! The method TryAdd() does not exist on my service object. Also Add() does not work, AddService() or similar does not exists. So I don't know how to add the AppService at my Startup.

Comment: @FrankMehlhop I guess you are missing some 'using's, I've edited the answer

Comment: I did it like that: 

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRepositories();
            services.AddBusinessComponents(); ...

And put my Services into the ServiceExtension.

Now it works. I'm very happy about. Thank you very much Felix B!!! :-)